# C++ std::enable_if in a class template, for a member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

The problem is simple. I have a header file with include guards and a implementation file .impl. Header file includes implementation file. I want to do the following:

Header file:

```
template<size_t N>
class A
{
  void func();
};
```

.impl file:

```
template<size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<(N <= 5), void>::type A<N>::func() { ... }

template<size_t N>
typename std::enable_if<(N > 5), void>::type A<N>::func() { ... }
```

However I am yet to be good with `std::enable_if` and it seems to fail to find the prototype for `func` because I change the function signature by changing the return type. How can I have different implementations while providing the user with one function for the interface.

This is essentially MCU register modifier that operates on two registers because one does not have the capacity. I'd rather not use any dirty offsets based on N inside the function and depend on plain structure. Also I'd rather not use helper functions which would complicate things if it is possible without them.

Comment: You're basically trying to partially specialize a "function template" (member function of a class template). This is not allowed. You can partially specialize the class template or use tag dispatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might delegate:

```
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N>
class A
{
    private:
    template <std::size_t I>
    typename std::enable_if<(I <= 5)>::type
    f() { std::cout << "Small\n"; }

    template <std::size_t I>
    typename std::enable_if<(I > 5)>::type
    f() { std::cout << "Big\n"; }

    public:
    void func() { f<N>(); }
};

int main()
{
    A<1> small;
    small.func();
    A<10> big;
    big.func();
}
```

And if you trust your compiler optimizations:

```
template<std::size_t N>
class A
{
    private:
    void small() { std::cout << "Small\n"; }
    void big() { std::cout << "Big\n"; }

    public:
    void func() {
        if(N <= 5) small();
        else big();
    }
};
```

Comment: I think this cannot be done for classes. Compiling fails with multiple errors, one saying cannot overload f... with other f... .

Comment: Ah yeah now I got it work. While up-voting both, I'll mark this as the answer, this feels more like _C++ way_ and gives a more control than true/false.

Comment: @etherealalone tag dispatching is a better way.  Usr SFINAE only when needed.  Read some C++ iterator library code...

Comment: @Yakk How can I have 3 do_func functions using tag dispatching, one <=5 one >5 && <= 15 and one >15 being invalid? Using tag dispatching, it seems like I will be needing to introduce new types for categorizing.

Comment: @erherealone daisy chain (`<=5` first, then `<15`), or take 2 parameters (`<=5` and `<15` -- only 3 overloads), or pass 0 1 2 `integral_constant`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [tag dispatching](http://www.generic-programming.org/languages/cpp/techniques.php#tag_dispatching) instead:

```
template <size_t N>
class A
{
    void func()
    {
        do_func(std::integral_constant<bool, (N > 5)>{});
    }

    void do_func(std::true_type) { /* handles the N > 5 case */ }
    void do_func(std::false_type) { /* handles the N <= 5 case */ }
};
```