# Implementing fast template array reset method

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, type-traits

I have a templated array class with a reset method. I want to optimize the reset code to use memset on PODs and a call for user-supplied reset() on non-PODs.

I want (1) The same name for the method (reset) and using the relevant implementation according to the template argument, and (2) Compile-time error if using a non-pod type T without a reset() function.

```
template <typename T>
class CArray {
private:
    T* array;
    size_t size;
public:
    void reset() {
        memset(array, 0, size);
    }
    void reset() {
        for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i)
            array[i].reset();
    }
}

CArray<int> arr1;
arr1.reset();                       -> will use memset and be fast
struct t2 { int* mem; void reset() {} };
CArray<t2> arr2;
arr2.reset();                      -> will call t2.reset for each element
struct t3 { int* mem; };
CArray<t3> arr3;
arr3.reset();                      -> should fail compilation since t3.reset() is missing
```

I tried playing a bit with type_traits, but I'm not sure if that's the right direction (can it help with compile-time checks)?

Comment: boost has a `enable_if`, some kind of SFINAE on POD-ness maby?

Comment: You can use SFINAE on `std::is_pod<T>`

Comment: It's possible you want 'trivially copyable' rather than POD. No matter, C++14 has a range of interesting templates such as `is_pod`, `is_trivially_copyable`, etc. Implementation is left as an exercise etc...

Comment: Consistent with user657267's point that `memset` is probably equal or worse than `std::fill`; another option is to call `reset()` if it exists, and `std::fill` if it doesn't, via SFINAE.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename T>
class CArray {
private:
    T* array;
    size_t size;
public:
    void reset() {
        CArrayReset( this );
    }
    void MemberReset()
    {
        for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i)
            array[i].reset();
    }
    void MemsetReset()
    {
        memset(array, 0, size);
    }
};

template <typename T>
typename disable_if<is_pod<T>, void>::type
CArrayReset( CArray<T>* arr )
{
    arr->MemberReset();
}

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<is_pod<T>, void>::type
CArrayReset( CArray<T>* arr )
{
    arr->MemsetReset();
}

void tryitout()
{
    CArray<int> arr1;
    arr1.reset();                     // will use memset and be fast
    struct t2 { int* mem; void reset() {} };
    CArray<t2> arr2;
    arr2.reset();                     // will call t2.reset for each element
    struct t3 { virtual void foo(){} int* mem; }; // added virtual func to make it non pod
    CArray<t3> arr3;
    arr3.reset();                     // will not compile
}
```

(various headers omitted)

Comment: There are two `void MemberReset()` member functions in your code.

Comment: On, sorry. They look too similar to me.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to force `memset` on PODs seems like a pointless "optimization" IMO

```
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

struct bar
{
  int i;
  int j;
};

std::array<bar, 4> test;

void foo()
{
  memset(&test, 0, sizeof test);
}

void foo2()
{
  test.fill(bar());
}
```

Compiling with `-O3 -c -S` gives me:

```
__Z3foov:
LFB944:
    movq    $0, _test(%rip)
    movq    $0, 8+_test(%rip)
    movq    $0, 16+_test(%rip)
    movq    $0, 24+_test(%rip)
    ret

...

__Z4foo2v:
LFB945:
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    movaps  %xmm0, _test(%rip)
    movaps  %xmm0, 16+_test(%rip)
    ret
```

Just concentrate on writing code that is easy to understand and let the compiler take care of optimizations. As long your classes have a default constructor you don't need to use SFINAE.

For your class the `reset` method could work as follows

```
void reset() {
  std::fill_n(array, size, T());
}
```

Comment: probably true; however he wants to call member function `.reset()` for non-PODs so his question remains

Comment: @MattMcNabb Well maybe, although I think once you remove the need to differentiate between PODs and non-PODs the question kind of disappears, assuming he wants to reset the contained data to a default state, i.e. he should provide default constructors for more complicated classes rather than a `reset` function.

Comment: That's an amazing feature from c++11. Too bad I'm limited by VC10 and the current data storage method of CArray (dumb T*)

Comment: @liorda You don't have to use `std::array`, you can just as well use any other container, or standard arrays and `std::fill` if you want the memory on the stack, or even just loop over the array. The point is that `memset` is probably not the answer.

Comment: @user657267 quite true also; moving from a default-constructed xvalue ought to have as good performance as `reset` would. Unless of course "reset" does something other than restore the object to its default state, e.g. does a counter of how many times the object has been reset!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use SFINAE on a non-template member function of a class template, because that would be partially specializing a function, which isn't permitted (thanks to dyp for [the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22972573/c-stdenable-if-in-a-class-template-for-a-member-function)).

However you can use *tag dispatching* quite easily, as that article suggests.

Demo code. Note, I've changed the array to use `std::vector` for memory management to make my demo simpler (actually it's unclear why your array doesn't do the same!)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

struct Baz
{
    void reset() { std::cout << "Baz reset" << std::endl; }
    Baz(int x = 1) { }
};

template <typename T>
struct CArray {   
    std::vector<T> ptr;

    void reset()
    {
        do_reset( std::is_pod<T>{} );
    }

private:
    void do_reset(std::true_type) { std::fill(ptr.begin(), ptr.end(), T()); }
    void do_reset(std::false_type) { for (auto &x : ptr) x.reset(); }
};

int main()
{
    CArray<int> x;
    x.ptr.push_back(1);
    x.reset();      // OK, no output

    CArray<std::string> y;
    // y.reset();   // compilation error - std::string has no member "reset"

    CArray<Baz> z;
    z.ptr.push_back( Baz() );
    z.reset();      // OK, output "Baz reset"
}
```